# Slicing a 20×20 area around known indices (x, y) in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have a large 2D numpy array for which I know a pair of indices which represent one element of the array. I want to set this element and the surrounding 20×20 area equal to zero; I have attempted using a slicing technique:

```
s = array[x:10, y:10]
s == 0
```

However, although x and y are previously defined, this is an 'invalid slice'.

I would appreciate any suggestions as to how I can accomplish this as I am new to Python.

Answer (score 3):

```
my_array[x - 10:x + 10, y - 10:y + 10] = 0
```

or

```
s = my_array[x - 10:x + 10, y - 10:y + 10]
s[:] = 0
```

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int' although this seems the correct method of slicing

Comment: @CandaceAdams: Then either `x` or `y` are a list instead of an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean `array[x:x+10,y:y+10]`

Comment: thanks, I tried this and it results in the following error; TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

Comment: what are x and y?  I assumed they integers indicating the top/left corner index?  If you already have x and y has like beg/end index, you need something like `array[x[0]:x[1]+1,y[0]:y[1]+1]`.  Also as other answers pointed out, the above soln capture 10x10 subarray.

Answer (score 0):

You select multiple elements of an array `A` with `A[start:stop]` where `start` and `stop` are zero-based indices.
For a 2D Array this applies as well: `A[start1:stop1, start2:stop2]`.

With the following script

```
import numpy as np

A = np.ones((5,5))
```

`A` looks like this

```
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]
```

with

```
A[1:4,1:4] = 0
```

you get

```
[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that for the block of zeros to be centered on your x,y coordinates, it must be of odd size. For instance, the block of zeros in the following is not centered the coordinates x,y = 4,6 but on the center coordinates of that cell, that is x, y = 4.5, 5.5:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.ones((10,10))
x,y = 4,6
s = 2
a[x - s: x + s, y-s: y + s] = 0

array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

whereas this one is:

```
a = numpy.ones((10,10))
x,y = 4,6
s = 2
a[x - s: x + s + 1, y-s: y + s + 1] = 0
print a

array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

If the script is for pixel based image processing, this could be an important distinction.