# Take a number of words centered at the specified one

Tags: python, algorithm

Could anybody tell me how I can consider the words around a given word? 
Example: If we have the sentence: "Today the weather is fine and we love to walk."
Then, if the window size is 5, I'd like to get the following:

- Today the weather (center: "Today")
- Today the weather is (center: "the")
- Today the weather is fine (center: "weather")
- the weather is fine and (center: "is")
- weather is fine and we (center: "fine")
- is fine and we love (center: "and")

and so on. 
Considering bigrams is no problem:

```
bigrams = [p for s in corpus_lemm for p in nltk.bigrams(w for w in s)] #take bigrams inside of each sentence
```

But how can I consider the words of the given window size?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't understand why those strings are generated when the window size is 5

Comment: Well, for the first example, the center is "today": 2 words before is nothing, 2 words after are "the" and "weather".
For the second example, the center is "the": 2 words before is "Today", 2 after: "weather" and "is".
For the third example, the center is "weather". 2 words before are "Today" and "the", 2 after: "is" and "fine.
4th example: The center is "is", 2 words before: "the" and "weather", 2 after: "fine" and "and". 
Etc.

Comment: List slicing is the simplest method. I leave the details to you as an exercise.

Comment: Your operation is undefined for an even "window size" btw.

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066410/slicing-a-20%C3%9720-area-around-known-indices-x-y-in-a-numpy-array

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i haven't got much control on Python but in JS one could do the job as follows. In hopes with, you can implement it into Python.

```js
var str = "Today the weather is fine and we love to walk.",
    arr = str.split(/\s+/),
    win = 5,
 result = arr.map((w,i,a) => Array(win).fill()
                                       .map((e,j) => a[i + j + -1 * Math.floor(win/2)])
                                       .reduce((p,c) => p ? c ? p + " " + c
                                                              : p
                                                          : c));
 console.log(result);
```

As per your comment... while sticking on the same algorithm i might extend my answer as follows.

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
    win = 5,
 result = arr.map((_,i,a) => Array(win).fill()
                                       .map((e,j) => a[i + j + -1 * Math.floor(win/2)])
                                       .reduce((p,c) => p ? c ? [].concat(p,c)
                                                              : p
                                                          : c ? c
                                                              : undefined));
 console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: Hm, but if I have the following array: a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]. The result should be: a[0:3], a[0:4], a[0:5], a[1:6], a[2:7], a[3:8], a[4:8], a[5:8]. Isn't there any solution which is  easier?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I could solve it using nltk's ngrams, which do pretty much the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure I understand the windowing, but seems to be the output that you want.

```
s = "Today the weather is fine and we love to walk"
words = s.split()
win_len = 5

half_win = win_len // 2

print "\n".join(words[:half_win])

for i in range(len(words) - win_len + 1):
    window = words[i:i+win_len]
    # print " ".join(window)
    print window[len(window) // 2]

print "\n".join(words[-half_win:])
```

Outputs

```
Today
the
weather
is
fine
and
we
love
to
walk
```

Comment: Hm, but if I have the following array: a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]. The result should be: a[0:3], a[0:4], a[0:5], a[1:6], a[2:7], a[3:8], a[4:8], a[5:8]. Isn't there any solution which is easier?

Comment: Define "easier". What is wrong with the answer I provided? It gives the output statements you wanted, no?

Comment: Maybe you could, I haven't used `ntlk`, so good luck with that

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list.index` and list slicing to retrieve the desired words.

```
def words(text, search, window):
    words = s.split()
    i = words.index(search)

    low = i - window // 2
    high = low + window
    low = max(low, 0)

    return words[low:high]
```